# django method not allowed (get,post) 405

Tags: django

First, I am not an English user and I am a beginner in django.

When i try to send a **put, patch, and delete** request to api, Method Not Allowed (GET): error occurs.

For example, Write down the code below using the patch.

views.py

```
class Boardapi_update(View):
    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {
            'pk': self.kwargs['pk'],
            'b_title': requests.POST.get['b_title'],
            'b_note': requests.POST.get['b_note']
        }

        url = 'http://localhost:8080/boardapi/'+str(data['pk'])+'/update/'

        bupdate = requests.patch(url, datas=data)
        # bupdate = requests.put(url, json={'query':data})
    
        print(bupdate)

        def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse('board_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.board.pk})
```

html

```
 <form action="{% url 'board_update' board_detail.b_no %}" id="frmBoard" method="patch">
 {% comment %} {%csrf_token%} {% endcomment %}
```

Comment: To be honest, I do not have a clue of what you would like to obtain here? Allowed methods for a form are available at runtime in a field of the same name. Put a breadpoint into your code and run the debugger to see, which methods are available.
For further support, please let me know, what the objective is?

Comment: It is sent to get request even if it is sent by patch, put, or delete.

Comment: Still no clue: Why is your `get_success_url` a sub method of your `patch` method? Shouldn't it be a `dispatch`? What would you print with a print command in the view? What are the unused variables for?

Comment: Print is just for checking. When i send requests.patch requests, the Chrome developer tool sends a request method as get, and 405 error occurs. and Get_process_url changed to return redirect(~~~~

Comment: I get the same error when I tap a submit form button that goes to the same page.